# Python Networkx or igraph DAG with duplicate ordered nodes and/or edges

Tags: python, graph, igraph, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

### The Problem

I'm working on building what we call a "variant graph" in genomics and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with Networkx. I'm open to creating my own code or another graph package.

### The Purpose

The overall purpose is to compare the two graphs below to count how many times a nucelotide (A, G, T, C) is found at each position, then return the letter with the highest count at each position to create a consensus sequence.

[image]

### Reference Graph

First, I need to build a graph that first creates a reference graph, as shown on the first line above, tracking the letter (nucleotide) found at each position.

So for the first graph below, each node would be named after the position:

```
node_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

With the following edges:

```
edges = [
(A,T),
(T,C),
(C,G),
(G,A),
(A,A),
(A,T),
(T,A),
(A,C)]
```

### Alternate Paths

Then to represent the variants shown in the second row of the picture, we would add alternative edges between positions 2 and 4 to represent the empty node, and between positions 7 and 8 to represent the inserted "T".

### What I've Tried

Since the graph needs to track multiple, directed edges I've tried the Networkx MultiDiGraph, but I am having trouble maintaining the order and managing the repeated edges.

### Desired Output

I would eventually like to add weights to each of the edges to count the number of times a nucleotide (letter)is seen at each position and use that information to determine the walk through the graph. So in table format, my desired output would look something like below showing the number of times each letter was seen at a position:

```
pos     |     A    |     T    |     G    |     C  
 0            53         29        101        23
 1            153        9         10         555   
 2            53         29        72         13
 3            53         29        101        23
 4            53         29        101        39
 5            53         29        101        39
 6            53         29        101        39
 7            53         29        101        39
 8            154        9         10         66
```

And from that data, I would return a consensus sequence of:

```
GCGGGGGGA
```

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
testRef = "GTCTAGGTCTAGGTCTAGAGTTAG"
start = 100

def create_edgelist(seq, truncate=True):
    while len(seq) >= 2:
        yield seq[:2]
        seq = seq[1:]
    if len(seq) and not truncate:
        yield seq

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
# add each ref node to graph by pos, nuc
[G.add_node(x + int(start)) for x,y in enumerate(testRef)]

for x, y in create_edgelist(testRef):
    G.add_edge(x, y)
```

Comment: Are your graphs always linear?

Comment: If your final output is the consensus sequence, what do you hope to achieve by framing the sequence alignment as a graph problem (given that there are standard sequence alignment tools that will give you just that)? Is this just for the purpose of visualisation?

Comment: It's going to be done on such a mass scale that I'm hoping it will be a more efficient data structure to solve the problem...